# sql query for getting both language

Tags: sql

I have student table with column as name and language. I have the below data.

[image]

I want to display student name who knows both java and c. I am new to sql, could you help me how to write the query?

Answer (score 4):

Group by the name and select only those having both languages

```
select name
from student
where language in ('java','c')
group by name
having count(distinct language) = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT l.name FROM students l
  JOIN students r
  ON l.name = r.name
  WHERE l.language = 'java'
    AND r.language = 'c';
```